# Synchronize local array with (SQLite) table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, python-3.3

I have an object that has three methods:

- `load()`:  Loads database table's contents into a local object-attribute-list
- `add()`: adds an element to the list
- `remove()`: removes an element from the list
- `save()`: Synchronizes the list with the database (this is where my question lies, details follow)

The first three methods are straight forward. But to synchronize the data back to the database-table, I want

- those elements that have changed to be `UPDATE`d/`REPLACE`d
- those that are new in the list and don't exist in the db table to be `INSERT`ed
- those that are removed from the list but still exist in the db-table to be `DELETE`d

Is there a way to do all that magic in *one* incredibly-elegant SQL command or would I need to do it in two steps, such as

- `INSERT OR REPLACE...` first, then
- `DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...`?

Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated. Please excuse me if there is an obvious solution to this that I have missed.

Comment: delete the lot in one go and then add again? :)

Comment: Well I can still do it in two steps, `INSERT OR REPLACE` new/changed data-sets first, then `DELETE` the dropped ones in a second pass. I guess I was hoping for a more elegant and efficient solution, but if that's what it takes then that's what it takes! :)
And that would obviously be more efficient than emptying the whole table and adding those sets back in that are to be kept.